# How can I keep markers on top of others with Google Static Maps API?

Tags: php, google-maps-static-api

I have a map with up to 25 pins being displayed. The first 9 are labeled 1-9, the rest are a generic dot marker.

[image: google static map with customizations, showing 9 on top of 8, but 5 on top of 7, as examples]

These markers are added in order: 1, 2, 3... 9, 10, 11. After 9 they are dots (google static maps only supports 1 digit markers).

**The problem:** The marker for #1 is being covered up by the smaller dot icons. They should be in the back. Similarly, marker #9 is covering up marker #8. Confusingly, marker #5 is on top of #7 - which is correct. Lower numbers should be on top, and the dotted markers should be in the back.

I have tried reversing the order of the markers on the URL, but this has no effect. I do not see any options for z-index using the Static Maps API.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Here is the embed code I am using (api key removed from the end):

```
http://maps.google.com.au/maps/api/staticmap?center=44.047708,-123.358691&size=640x320&maptype=roadmap&path=fillcolor:0xbca16533%7Ccolor:0x13131300%7Cenc:icalGzn|oVfAyj@pE_j@vIgh@zMwe@nQqb@|Tq^zW_ZhZ}Th\mOp]sIl^oCn^n@`^tF~\pLj[fRbYpWlVj\fSr`@vOfd@xK`g@tGdi@jClj@?zj@kClj@uGbi@yKbg@wOdd@gSr`@mVj\cYpWk[fR_]pLa^tFo^p@m^qCq]sIi\mOiZ}T{W_Z}Tq^oQob@{Mye@wIgh@qE}i@gAyj@&style=feature%3Aall%7Celement%3Aall%7Cvisibility%3Aon%7Csaturation%3A-100%7Cgamma%3A0.54%7C&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Alabels.icon%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C&style=feature%3Awater%7Celement%3Aall%7Ccolor%3A0x4d4946%7C&style=feature%3Apoi%7Celement%3Alabels.icon%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C&style=feature%3Apoi%7Celement%3Alabels.text%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Ageometry.fill%7Ccolor%3A0xffffff%7C&style=feature%3Aroad.local%7Celement%3Alabels.text%7Cvisibility%3Asimplified%7C&style=feature%3Awater%7Celement%3Alabels.text.fill%7Ccolor%3A0xffffff%7C&style=feature%3Atransit.line%7Celement%3Ageometry%7Cgamma%3A0.48%7C&style=feature%3Atransit.station%7Celement%3Alabels.icon%7Cvisibility%3Aoff%7C&style=feature%3Aroad%7Celement%3Ageometry.stroke%7Cgamma%3A7.18%7C&markers=color:black%7clabel:1%7c44.049727,-123.359269&markers=color:black%7clabel:2%7c44.070205,-123.363716&markers=color:black%7clabel:3%7c44.038696,-123.348037&markers=color:black%7clabel:4%7c44.032207,-123.352058&markers=color:black%7clabel:5%7c44.034713,-123.345176&markers=color:black%7clabel:6%7c44.041244,-123.342079&markers=color:black%7clabel:7%7c44.037186,-123.347408&markers=color:black%7clabel:8%7c44.0685,-123.357345&markers=color:black%7clabel:9%7c44.067466,-123.361381&markers=color:black%7csize:mid%7c44.065919,-123.32467%7c44.061237,-123.316459%7c44.052089,-123.348838%7c44.06039,-123.315452%7c44.046916,-123.356956%7c44.044887,-123.36296%7c44.067543,-123.356369%7c44.046884,-123.355275%7c44.042713,-123.363914%7c44.047252,-123.362197%7c44.06151,-123.317522
```

Here is a more legible var_dump of the markers array, which simply goes through implode() to be added to the URL:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:1%7c44.049727,-123.359269"
  [1]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:2%7c44.070205,-123.363716"
  [2]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:3%7c44.038696,-123.348037"
  [3]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:4%7c44.032207,-123.352058"
  [4]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:5%7c44.034713,-123.345176"
  [5]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:6%7c44.041244,-123.342079"
  [6]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:7%7c44.037186,-123.347408"
  [7]=> string(52) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:8%7c44.0685,-123.357345"
  [8]=> string(54) "&markers=color:black%7clabel:9%7c44.067466,-123.361381"
  [9]=> string(291) "&markers=color:black%7csize:mid%7c44.065919,-123.32467%7c44.061237,-123.316459%7c44.052089,-123.348838%7c44.06039,-123.315452%7c44.046916,-123.356956%7c44.044887,-123.36296%7c44.067543,-123.356369%7c44.046884,-123.355275%7c44.042713,-123.363914%7c44.047252,-123.362197%7c44.06151,-123.317522"
}
```

Just as an example, I have tried reversing this array before imploding it using:

```
$MapMarkers = array_reverse( $MapMarkers );
```

Comment: You might have to switch to the JS API, which has a [zIndex](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) option when placing a marker.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible. There is a feature request for that [35819311](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35819311) (marker zIndex for static map).